# sublime text 3 not sending code to sublimeREPL

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I installed Sublime Text 3. I installed Package Control, R-Box, SendText, SendCode, sublimeREPL, and 1337 Color Scheme. To test that REPL R is working I ran the code:

```
getwd()
```

The output was

```
R:/R_WD.
```

That's the correct location.
What I want to do is send code from one window to REPL R and have it evaluated. It originally would send code to the REPL R window and I could run the code but I wanted to be able to have it run automatically. I tried looking on forums for ideas and changed some settings. Now it will not send code to REPL R.

Here are my settings:
Preferences --> Package Settings --> R-Box --> Settings:

```
{
   // enable auto completions
   "auto_completions": true,

   // show popup hints
   "show_popup_hints": true,

   // path to Rscript, for example
   // (mac, linux): "/usr/local/bin/Rscript"
   // (windows):    "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-x.y.z\\bin\\Rscript.exe"
   "rscript_binary": null,

   // additional paths to PATH variable
   "additional_paths": []
}
```

User:

```
{
  "prog": "Cmder",
}
```

Preferences --> Package Settings --> SendText --> Settings---> Default:

```
{
    // Uncomment the program you want send text to:
    "program": "Terminal.app",
    // "program": "iTerm",
    // "program": "tmux",
    // "program": "screen",
    "paths":
    {
        // It might be necessary to explicitly set path (usually /usr/bin
        // or /usr/local/bin) to tmux and screen. Uncomment below and specify
        // the correct path:
        // "tmux": "/usr/local/bin/tmux",
        // "screen": "/usr/local/bin/screen"
    }
}
```

Preferences --> Package Settings --> SendText --> Settings---User:

```
    {
      "prog": "Cmder",
    }
```

Preferences --> Package Settings --> SendCode--> Settings:

```
    {
       "prog": "Cmder",
    }
```

Preferences --> Package Settings -->SublimeREPL--> Settings---Default:

```
{
    // default_extend_env are used to augment any environment variables
    // that should be visible for all subprocess repls launched within
    // SublimeREPL. This is a very good place to add PATH extension
    // once "PATH": "{PATH}:/home/username/mylocalinstalls/bin" or whatever
    "default_extend_env": {},

    // Specify whether to move repls to a different Sublime Text group (frame)
    // immediately on opening. Setting this to true will simply move it to
    // the 'next' group from the one that was in focus when it was opened
    // (one down with row layout, one to the right with column and grid
    // layout). Alternatively, you can set this to the index of the group in
    // which you want all repls to be opened (index 0 being the top-left group).
    // Activating this option will NOT automatically change your layout/create
    // a new group if it isn't open.
    "open_repl_in_group": true,

    // Persistent history is stored per REPL external_id, it means that all python
    // REPLS will share history. If you wish you can disable history altogether
    "persistent_history_enabled": true,

    // By default SublimeREPL leaves REPL view open once the underlying subprocess
    // dies or closes connection. This is useful when the process dies for an unexpected
    // reason as it allows you to inspect it output. If you want. Setting this
    // to true will cause SublimreREPL to close view once the process died.
"view_auto_close": false,

    // On POSIX system SublimeText launched from GUI does not inherit
    // a proper environment. Often leading to problems with finding interpreters
    // or not using the ones affected by changes in ~/.profile / *rc files
    // This command is used as a workaround, it's launched before any subprocess
    // repl starts and it's output is parsed as an environment
"getenv_command": ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c", "env"],

    // Some terminals output ascii color codes which are not currently supported
    // enable this option to filter them out.
"filter_ascii_color_codes": true,

    // Where to look for python virtualenvs
"python_virtualenv_paths": [
    "~/.virtualenvs",  // virtualenvwrapper
    "~/.venv"  // venv.bash https://github.com/wuub/venv
],

    // Use arrows for history navigation instead of Alt+[P|N]/Ctrl+[P|N]
"history_arrows": true,

    // standard sublime view settings that will be overwritten on each repl view
    // this has to be customized as a whole dictionary
    "repl_view_settings": {
        "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
        "auto_indent": false,
        "smart_indent": false,
        "spell_check": false,
        "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
        "detect_indentation": false,
        "auto_complete": true,
        "line_numbers": false,
        "gutter": false
    },

    // this settings exposes additional variables in repl config files, especially
    // those related to sublime projects that are not available through standard API
    // WARNING: this will switch your build system back to Automatic each time a REPL
    // is started so beware!
    "use_build_system_hack": false,

    // IP address used to setup autocomplete server in sublimerepl.
    // changing this is usefull when you want to exclude one address
    // from proxychains/tsocks routing
    "autocomplete_server_ip": "127.0.0.1",

    // Mapping is used, when external_id of REPL does not match
    // source.[xxx] scope of syntax definition used to highlight
    // files from which text is being transfered. For example octave
    // repls use source.matlab syntax files and w/o this mapping text transfer
    // will not work
"external_id_mapping": {
    "octave": "matlab"
},

    // If set to true, SublimeREPL will try to append evaluated code to repl
    // output before evaluation (e.g. Ctrl+, f)
    "show_transferred_text": true,

    // If set to true repl view (tab) that receives text for evaluation will
    // be brought to front after text transfer. Note: This will not fire if repl 
view
    // is in the same tab group as the view from which the code is sent.
    "focus_view_on_transfer": true
}
```

Preferences --> Package Settings -->SublimeREPL-->Settings--- User:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};R:\\R_WD\\R\\R-3.4.2\\bin\\x64"},
    "show_transferred_text": true
}
```

I noticed that the comments said to uncomment or add code but I can't seem to edit the code in those locations.
 Any help is appreciated. If there is any clarification needed, I'm happy to provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I changed the code to get it to work:

I changed "Preferences --> Package Settings --> SendText --> Settings---User:" from:

```
{
  "prog": "Cmder",
}
```

to:

```
{"r" : {
       "prog": "cmder",
    }
    { "rscript_binary" :  "R:\\R_WD\\R\\R-3.4.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe"
    }
}
```

All the other user settings code that was:

```
{
  "prog": "Cmder",
}
```

I changed to:

```
{"r" : {
       "prog": "cmder",
    }
}
```

I can now send the code to be automatically evaluated with the default option.